# how to create a table in redshift from multiple json files in S3

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

I wanted to know if there is a possibility to create a single table containing all the JSON files from an s3 bucket, I've searched a lot and I can't find a solution for this, if anyone can help with any tips I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but it is not clear what your intent is.  If you have a bucket with a set of json files that are in a Redshift readable format and have common data that can be mapped into columns, then this is fairly straight forward.  The COPY command can read all the files in the bucket and apply a common mapping to the tables columns.  Is this what you want?

Or do you have a bunch of dissimilar json files in various structures that you want to load some information from each into a Redshift table?  Then you will likely want to use a Glue Crawler to inventory the jsons and load them separately into Redshift and then combine the common information into a single Redshift table.

Plus there are many other possibilities of what you need.  The bottom line is that you are asking to load many unstructured files into a structured database.  There is some mapping that needs to happen but depending on what your data looks like this can be fairly simple or quite complex.